# Выполнение JS кода между перезагрузками страницы

Tags: javascript

Есть кривая админка интернет магазина, в которой есть список товаров. Напротив каждого товара есть кнопки "Выше" и "Ниже" что перемещает товар выше/ниже на одну строку в магазине. Кнопки скрывают за собой подобный JS код:

```
javascript: move('catalog_elements','up',273);
```

Код функции move:

```
function move(fwhere,fwhat,fid) {
    document.command_form.command.value='move';
    document.command_form.where.value=fwhere;
    document.command_form.what.value=fwhat;
    document.command_form.id.value=fid;
    document.command_form.submit();
}
```

После вызова этой функции идет перезагрузка всей страницы, поэтому я вроде как не могу просто засунуть вызов в for и поднять товар сразу на несколько строчек вверх. Или могу? Каким образом?

Кусок разметки с формой:

```
<form action="" id="command_form" name="command_form" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="command" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="where" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="what" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="">
</form>
```

Comment: зависит от того, что внутри этого `move`. приведите весь код..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите у формы `command_form` атрибуты `action` (по умолчанию `.`) и `method` (по умолчанию `GET`). Ну а потом делайте AJAX-запрос вроде этого:

```
http://example.com/path?command=move&where=catalog_elements&what=up&id=273
```

Можете повторить его столько раз, сколько вам надо, а потом перезагрузите страницу (или сделайте последний вызов не асинхронным, а прежним способом — через отправку формы).

Запрос формировать можно вручную и отправлять с помощью `XMLHttpRequest`, а можно воспользоваться благами цивилизации: jQuery и плагином [Ajax Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) — это уже по вкусу. [Примеры jQuery AJAX submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form).

Comment: @graalogosh Собственно, отправляйте POST запрос на тот URL, который отображается в адресной строке браузера. В качестве тела запроса используйте строку из ответа.

Answer (score 3):

Сложно сказать что там происходит точно, не увидев еще и серверного кода, но "просто засунуть в for" не можете.

В общих чертах вашу задачу можно решить так:

1. Хороший путь - переписать все используя ajax вместо сабмита формы (что в соседнем ответе описывает Athari)
2. Возможно (зависит от того что на сервере) более быстрый с точки зрения трудозатрат путь: добавить обработку параметра "на сколько позиций сдвигаем" на сервере, соответственно добавить в форму и функцию такой параметр
3. Пути для больных извращенцев, вроде считать количество отправок формы где-нибудь в localStorage